# java swt memory leak

Tags: java, memory-leaks, swt

I have java swt code in which there is memory leak that I could be able to find where it is but not able to resolve it. Here is my code that has the memory leak,

```
void refreshMyPanel(){
    Control[] oldControls = my_group.getChildren();

    //do sth

    for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
        Label label1_lin = new Label(linear_img_group, SWT.NONE);

        // first option
    //  label1_lin.setImage(SWTResourceManager.getImage( "C:\\Users\\Public\\Pictures\\Sample Pictures\\p1.jpg"));

        // second option
    //  label1_lin.setImage(SWTResourceManager.getImage(linear_list.get(i)));

        label1_lin.setBounds(x0, y0, xSize, ySize);
    }

    for (Control oldControl : oldControls)
        oldControl.dispose();

    //do sth
}
```

I'm calling `refreshMyPanel()` method 60 times and when I uncomment `first option` at the end of 60 calls the memory usage of Java SWT application becomes around 60 MB, when I call `second option` it becomes 360 MB.

Most likely, it is not automatically disposing the image but how will I dispose it?

I'm using eclipse kepler on windows environment.

**ADDITIONAL TEST**: When I get image by

```
Image img = new Image(display, linear_list.get(i);
labe1_lin.setImage(img);
```

the memory usage becomes around 1.3 GB, and when I dispose it gives exception again. 
Thanks,

Comment: It's not a memory leak; the 60MB is the application caching the 360 images you're getting from calling the method 60 times. I'd imagine storing them in a list isn't as optimised as calling the path directly.

Comment: To make sure that it's a memory leak, you could create the `Image` instances yourself and then add a `Listener` for `SWT.Dispose` to each `Label` which will then call `dispose()` on the `Image` obtained from `Label#getImage()` (if it hasn't already been disposed).

Comment: @Gorb: It is definitely a leak that is caused by either me or java. I'm calling that method 1000 times instead of 60, now the memory usage is around 3 GB. Related to `first option is 60 MB, second 360 MB`, I think, it maybe because of java optimizations, it is loading once instead of 6 times for each call of `refreshMyPanel()`

Comment: @Baz: I have already tried it but when I do that it gives `org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Graphic is disposed` exception.

Comment: @smttsp That's why you should always check `!isDisposed()` before calling `dispose()`.

Comment: @Baz I checked if it is disposed, in the second call of `refreshMyPanel()`, it gives the same exception instead of first call.

Comment: @smttsp `isDisposed()` does not throw an exception.

Comment: It may also be that the JRE has plenty of memory available in the heap and so it has not bothered to run garbage collection yet.

Comment: @Baz, I deleted `try-catch` still the same exception. The problem is, I think, when I call `label1.setImage(SWTResourceManager(img))`, it loads the image to memory then it is not removing. Those images should already be disposed as I'm disposing labels at the end of the `refreshMyPanel()`. I editted the code.

Comment: @greg-449 How could I run garbage collection? After 1200 call of refreshMyPanel it gives exception that `No more resources available` how could it Java not initiate garbage collection?

Comment: That's why I wrote _"create the `Image` instances yourself"_. Don't use `SWTResourceManager` for this test.

Comment: If you are getting `no more resources available` you are not disposing things properly and garbage collection will not help.

Comment: @Baz: Yeah, this is what I was thinking at the beginning, then came to that result at the end as if I found something new

Comment: @greg-449: how can you dispose `Image img = SWTResourceManager.getImage(linear_list.get(i)); label1_lin.setImage(img);`

Comment: I don't use `SWTResourceManager` but from the source it looks like you use `SWTResourceManager.disposeImages()` (or `SWTResourceManager.dispose()`)

Comment: What are you using for adding images to your shell or a label etc? I don't mind changing how I'm adding images to labels as long as it is working without problems. I have some more leaks in the code but they are in acceptable levels, this leak causes the program to crash.

Comment: @smttsp How do you try to dispose the images? And what does `linear_list` contain?

Comment: @Baz I add them to label and at the end of the method I dispose the label. But I think, this doesn't dispose images, does it? How can I dispose images given that `Image img = SWTResourceManager.getImage(linear_list(i)); ... img.dispose()` is giving exception. `linear_list` is an arraylist that has the directories of images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do something like this:

```
void refreshMyPanel(){
    Control[] oldControls = my_group.getChildren();

    for (Control oldControl : oldControls)
        oldControl.dispose();

    for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
        Label label = new Label(linear_img_group, SWT.NONE);

        Image image = new Image(Display.getDefault(), linear_list.get(i));

        label.setImage(image);

        label.addListener(SWT.Dispose, new Listener()
        {
            @Override
            public void handleEvent(Event e)
            {
                Label thisLabel = (Label) e.widget;
                Image thisImage = thisLabel.getImage();
                if(!thisImage.isDisposed();
                    thisImage.dispose();
            }
        });

        label1_lin.setBounds(x0, y0, xSize, ySize);
    }
}
```

---

Alternatively, create the 6 `Image`s once before you run your 100-iteration loop, use them without disposing in `refreshMyPanel` and then `dispose` them once you are done.

Comment: Thanks a lot that worked. Could you please explain me why you added listener? Why couldn't I be able to dispose simply by `img.dispose()` Also, should I always dispose like this or using dispose() method works too? And how will I understand how to dispose?

Comment: @smttsp Well, you have to dispose the image eventually, but you don't know exactly when. If you dispose it too early, you'll get an exception because the label is still expecting the image to be available. If you dispose it too late, you might run out of memory. The listener checks when the label is disposed and then directly disposes the image. Consequently the image only "lives" as long as it has to. Remember that this only works because you use each image only once in the loop. Otherwise you would have to take care of special cases.

Comment: That means, it is best to dispose using listener if I'm not totally sure when to dispose something, right?

Comment: You should load and cache the images. Disposing and recreating resources is not a good approach and expensive. You should look at using ImageRegistry (sort of) to cache images.

Comment: @sambireddy I'm aware that the first suggestion isn't optimal. That's why I suggested the second solution.

Comment: @sambireddy and Baz, that is logical, but for now it is not a bottleneck and it doesn't cause any problem. This is only needed for a short demo. As long as it doesn't crash, it is ok. Still good to know that, thanks.